# jquery ui shake effect not working?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add shake effect to a particular image as per client request.

The image is not shaking in spite of me having everything right to the best of my knowledge.

```
<div id="shake"><img src="./index_files/image-gallery3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).click(function(){
    $("#shake").effect("shake");});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work - **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwachtler/YvJhE/763/)** are there any errors in the console log?

Comment: You sure you've inlcuded the jquery and jquery ui sources into your page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include this dude:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```